# How to bind ListboxItem as observable collection in WPF and insert new record at the Top

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to display all the messages I am receiving from backend into a list box like

> *10:12:23 Login Successful.*
>
> *10:13:00 Logout Successful.*

How can a bind this string message as listitem with auto updation through ***INotifyPropertyChange*** and with the condition that recent item should get inserted at 0th index.

Comment: Have you tried anything to make it work?

Comment: Actually i am very new to WPF so initially i want to know which property do i need to bind for message to display. I am not getting any example just every body is using itemsource to a list which in my case is not working.

Comment: We need to see your code and a more detailed explanation what "which in my case is not working" means.

Comment: You should have an `ObservableCollection<YourItemData>` in your viewmodel, then bind this as `ItemsSource`. This will enable you to add new items at any index inside the collection and have them show up in the view. Also, you need to provide a `DataTemplate` for `YourItemData`, which will define the look and functionality of your list items. `YourItemData` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to update the view when the properties of an existing item are modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quickly going to throw the code in pieces; you'll have to assemble it.

> every body is using itemsource to a list which in my case is not
>   working.

You cannot leave it as `{Binding}` that works if you set list's data context to collection. But if your collection is part of view-model then you must specify collection name in binding.

**View**:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}" />
<Button Click="AddLogEntry_Click" Content="Add log entry" />
```

**View-Model**:

```
public class ViewModel1 : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> logs;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Logs {
        get {
            if (logs == null)
                logs = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            return logs;
        }
    }

    // This is added for test
    public void AddLogEntry() {
        Logs.Insert(0, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

**View Code-Behind**:

```
ViewModel1 vm;

public DisplayLatestItemInListbox() {
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new ViewModel1();
    DataContext = vm;
}

// Use command instead.
private void AddLogEntry_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    vm.AddLogEntry();
}
```

Key here is to use `Insert` method on `ObservableCollection`. And here's what you get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this sample as follow this will help you,

**View Model :**

```
    public VM()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        Items.Insert(0, "The time now is " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) };
        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            Items.Insert(0,"The time now is " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
        };
        timer.Start();
    }



    private ObservableCollection<string> items;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return items; }

    }
```

Bind this item to XAML listview